# Why don't certain pins on PORTC on the ATmega164A/324Pa/644PA/1284P work?

Tags: atmega, jtag, atmega1284p

I want to use the PC2 pin on my ATmega164-1284PA series of microcontrollers and it's not working no matter what I do. I even wrote a minimal test case that only sets it as an output and toggles the pin with a one second delay. Not even that works. What's the problem?

Answer (score 6):

I wasted a lot of time on this. You need to disable JTAG with the fuse bits to use PC2, PC3, PC4 and PC5.

According to the datasheet

```
in reset. When programmed, the input TAP signals are internally pulled high and the JTAG is enabled for
Boundary-scan and programming. The device is shipped with this fuse programmed.
```

This means that for the pins to act as regular pins you need to disable JTAG.

Comment: You don't need to change any fuses. Just disable JTAG from the MCUCR.